# Grails custom tag out<<

Tags: grails, tags

I'm testing creating tags in grails.

```
class HiWorldtagLib{

   def sayhi={attrs,body->
        def msg="<h1>Hello"+attrs.name+"</h1>";
        out<<msg;
   }

}

 <HiWorld:sayhi name="world"/>
```

It runs through my tag code but only spits out the HTML with comment `<!--` wrapped around it. And also the tag itself in lower case.

Rendered html...

```
<body>
    <!--<h1>Hello world</h1>-->
    <hiworld:sayhi name="world"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default namespace is `g`

Try this one

```
<g:sayhi name="world"/>
```

If you want to keep your namespace, you should add the following property in the taglib class:

```
static namespace = "HiWorld"
```

Comment: Awesome. Easy fix. Though I'm curious why Grails still chooses to run and output with comment tags if my namespace is wrong?